# Rails: Updating two fields of an ActiveRecord instance simultaniously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, field

I have a model, called `Book`, that has the fields `title` and `filename` (and other fields but they are unrelated). I'd like that the `filename` field was automatically created using the title, thus in my *Book.rb*:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def title=(title)
    self.filename = sanitize_filename(title)
    self.title = title
  end

  # ...
end
```

Because of `self.title = title` it's going in a infinite recursion. How could I avoid that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
class Book
  def title=(title)
    self.filename = sanitize_filename(title)
    self[:title] = title
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for. I've seen the same idea in Python. Thank you very much! Wonder how could I've been programming without knowing this... Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2):

You can write that on before_save

```
def before_save
  self.filename = sanitize_filename(self.title)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of that, too, but I wanted a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a section in the [ActiveRecord api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) on 'overwriting default accessors'. The suggested solution there is:

```
def title=(t)
  self.filename = sanitize_filename(t)
  write_attribute(:title, t)
end
```

Comment: I was looking for exactly this part of the doc, but thought that someone might already know that so they could help me out. Thanks a lot!